# Configuring SSO on Bluemix

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I am trying to configure SSO on bluemix, and I added the SSO service in my dashboard, unbound to any application as the documentation says.

But when I click on it to configure it, it ask me to name it. I just write an alphanumeric name, and then the bluemix console will wait up to a dozen minutes before answering "ERROR: env: Client Internal Error.

This is a showstopping bug because I need this step to proceed.

Any ideas?

[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUkMV.png)

Answer (score 1):

Hello it looks like a temporary issue with Bluemix console or at least with the SSO one, not with the SSO service itself.
I suggest you you to try again in few minutes, to check if the issue has been solved.
In order to check about Bluemix overall status and about all its services you could have a look of Bluemix status page at h
https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status

If the issue isn't solved yet you could open a support request directly from your Bluemix console using the support/help widget or sending an email to support@bluemix.net : by this way you could involve Bluemix support team in checking and fix this issue.