# Can't create SSO service in Bluemix Console

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I am not able to create an SSO service. Earlier I was seeing errors similar to those mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263886/configuring-sso-on-bluemix). Now it seems to be creating the service, but where I usually see the selections to use SAML, Facebook, etc, I just see a blank, white space.

I don't see anything in [the status page](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status) indicating that there is a known problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am aware of a temporary problem for SSO service yesterday morning (UTC) also reported in the status page. Today the service seems to be up and running and no issues have been reported yet. From the time you asked the question in this forum, I think you might have seen some tailing problems while the service was coming back alive.
If you still should see this behavior today I suggest you to inform Bluemix Support as described in the post you linked in your question.